# Darauf auf / Den Handelsweg /

Tags: word-choice, preposition, pronominal-adverb

What is the purpose of the word `darauf` in the following paragraph? They probably added it by mistake.

> Zudem ist zu befürchten, dass Russland wegen der jüngsten Zerstörung seiner Krim-Brücke militärische Vergeltung suchen könnte – dies drohte Präsident Wladimir Putin jedenfalls an, ohne konkret zu werden. Auch wenn nach offiziellen Aussagen die Ablehnung einer Verlängerung des Abkommens nichts mit dem Angriff auf die Brücke zu tun gehabt habe, ist natürlich nicht ausgeschlossen, dass sich die russische Antwort darauf auf den ukrainischen Handelsweg konzentriert.

Source:https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/europa/getreideabkommen-reaktionen-verlaengerung-106.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That *darauf* refers back to *Angriff auf die Brücke*. The reason why that *da*-adverb features *auf* is because the relevant verb phrase is *auf etwas antworten*, hence *die Antwort auf etwas* or *die Antwort darauf*.